# How to add classes to an element outside of AlpineJS element

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have a simple question but it's driving me mad to work out.
I'm using AlpineJS to show and hide content.
Normally with alpine, the button and content will be in the same element, but here I have it outside of it. This works.
But I cannot add classes to both the button and content div when the content is open or closed.

Can anyone guide me please.

```
<!-- button -->
<div class="mt-4" x-data="{id: 1}">
    <button 
    @click="$dispatch('open-dropdown',{id})" 
    type="button" 
    class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-50"
    :class="{ 'bg-green-400': open, 'bg-gray-200': !(open) }">
        I'm the button
    </button>
</div>

<!-- popup 1 -->
<div x-data="{ open: false }" 
x-show="open" 
@open-dropdown.window="if ($event.detail.id == 1) open = true" 
@click.away="open = false">
    <div
    class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-50"
    :class="{ 'bg-green-400': open, 'bg-gray-200': !(open) }">
        I'm the content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can move the `open` state inside the global [Alpine.js' `$store`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) object that is accessible for all component on the page.

```
<!-- button -->
<div class="mt-4" x-data="{id: 1}">
  <button @click="$dispatch('open-dropdown',{id})"
          type="button"
          class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-50"
          :class="{ 'bg-green-400': $store.open, 'bg-gray-200': !($store.open) }">
      I'm the button
  </button>
</div>

<!-- popup 1 -->
<div x-data
     x-show="$store.open"
     @open-dropdown.window="if ($event.detail.id == 1) $store.open = true"
     @click.away="$store.open = false">
  <div class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-50"
        :class="{ 'bg-green-400': $store.open, 'bg-gray-200': !($store.open) }">
    I'm the content
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.store('open', false)
})
</script>
```

Since our `open` state in the store is a simple value, we can just replace every `open` with `$store.open`. Note that the `popup 1` component still requires an empty `x-data` attribute.

Comment: thank you so much! it works perfectly! and also thanks for the explanation, I'm studying and this really helps me.

Comment: is there a way to have multiple buttons and content?

Comment: I tried adapting the code but the buttons were interfering with each other.

Comment: You want to create as many state variables as many independent functionality you have in your app. Otherwise they all will use the same state variable which is not the desired behavior. The [store](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) supports object data type as well, so you can group these state variables together if you wish.

Comment: So like this https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/state under global state where they mention items: ['first', 'second', 'third'],

Comment: In that "tabs" example, the `tabs` variable in the store is an object that has two attributes: `current` and `items`. The `items` is an array. But you only need boolean true/false variables to track the open state of your popups. So you can create a object in the store, e.g. `popups` with attributes: `pop1`, `pop2`, etc, all of them having a `true` or `false` default value. When you want to open your popup1 you just switch `$store.popups.pop1` to `true`.

Comment: Perfect! now I understand. Thanks again Dauros. I really appreciate it.